# Selenium looping through jenkins and permission denied in cli

Tags: command-line, selenium, jetty

After struggling to get proper testsuites, I'm now pretty disappointed by the fact that , while following as close as possible this tutorial (pretty straightforward, right ?) [Setting up Selenium server on a headless Jenkins CI build machine](http://www.labelmedia.co.uk/blog/posts/setting-up-selenium-server-on-a-headless-jenkins-ci-build-machine.html), Jenkins keeps looping on the current build, outputting :

[image: jenkins log output]

So I decided to run a selenium build by hand on the ci machine, and got this :

```
user@machine:/var/log$ export DISPLAY=":99" && java -jar /var/lib/selenium/selenium-  server.jar -browserSessionReuse -htmlSuite *firefox http://staging.site.com /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project/workspace/tests/selenium/testsuite.html /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project/workspace/logs/selenium.html
24 janv. 2012 19:27:56 org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a standalone server
19:27:59.927 INFO - Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. 20.0-b11
19:27:59.929 INFO - OS: Linux 3.0.0-14-generic amd64
19:27:59.951 INFO - v2.17.0, with Core v2.17.0. Built from revision 15540 
19:27:59.958 INFO - Will recycle browser sessions when possible. 
19:28:00.143 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
19:28:00.144 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
19:28:00.145 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
19:28:00.147 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
19:28:00.147 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
19:28:00.183 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@16ba8602
19:28:00.184 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
19:28:00.199 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444
19:28:00.199 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@6f7a29a1
HTML suite exception seen:
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
  at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
  at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:900)
  at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.runHtmlSuite(SeleniumServer.java:603)
  at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.boot(SeleniumServer.java:287)
  at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.main(SeleniumServer.java:245)
  at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher.main(GridLauncher.java:54)
19:28:00.218 INFO - Shutting down...
19:28:00.220 INFO - Stopping Acceptor ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=4444]
```

While understanding the output is'nt that hard, finding what to do to remove this issue is.

Any chance you guys already have been facing that kind of stuff ? Thanks

Comment: Your second problem points an access right problem regarding the result file "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project/workspace/logs/selenium.html". Are you sure that the user "user" from the shell example has write access to Jenkins workspace. I'm sure your first problem (not ending job in Jenkins) has to have another cause otherwise you would see the same (access right) error description in Jenkins log.

Answer (score 0):

I only just got past these problems myself, but I was able to run your command when I pointed it at my .jar, testSuite and report file. I'm thinking that perhaps the location of your files under,

```
/var/lib/selenium
```

could be part of the problem. Try putting them where your user has permission perhaps under

```
/home/USERNAME/selenium
```

Other than that the only thing I can say is make sure your .jar, testSuite and report file are valid.

Also (I assume this is an error of copy and paste into stack overflow) but, this part of your command is incorrect

```
/var/lib/selenium/selenium-  server.jar
```

You are not getting the error I would expect from an incorrect jar location so I assume something was lost when you pasted to stackoverflow.